# Set Button shortcut Without Command?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-4.0

Its Simple Repeated Question:

> How set shortcut for buttons (ButtonBase-Element) **without Command Binding**?

I test ***AccessKeyManager***, but I want to set Shorcuts with Modifier.
and Ppossible to do this with Code?

> For example:
>
> F1 .. F12
> Ctrl + a .. z
> Ctrl + F1 .. F12

Comment: Then it doesn't have *anything* to do with the button, use a command binding...

Comment: @HB : I use button Click Events, kind of Classic Ways :)

Comment: I think you did not understand my point: If you just press a bunch of keys (which are not access keys) to execute some code you no longer interact with the button at all hence it is only logical that the button does not provide this functionality. And nor should you provide it, it's convoluted. Refactor the logic into a command and bind both the button and a command binding to the same command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could give you a general idea on how you would go about things

```
    Keys lastkey = Keys.None;
    Button b = new Button();
    private void KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastkey == Keys.Control)
        {
            //Do some stuff
            b.PerformClick();
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Control)
            lastkey = Keys.Control;
        else
            lastkey = e.KeyCode;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , but it's like old classic way, I looking for better way